How to upgrade a multi-architecture installation from Jammy to Noble?
This is a Parallels VM running on an ARM Mac with the support enabled for running x86 binaries under Rosetta.
/etc/apt/sources.list has been expanded to pairs of lines like this:
deb [arch=arm64]  http://us.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted
deb [arch=amd64]  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

apt seems quite happy with this. But attempting to upgrade fails with complaints that it can't find amd64 packages on us.ports.ubuntu.com.
Is this a bug in the upgrade tool? Is there a workaround?
Here are some screenshots:




Also, "sudo do-release-upgrade -d" fails in essentially the same way - complaining about 404s trying to fetch amd64 stuff from ports.

amd64 is NOT a port architecture; thus packages are NOT expected at ports.ubuntu.com .   You've provided no commands are details of what was done for the error messages you provided (and thus far I'd expect user error the mostly likely as you're without specifics that would rule this out)

There are no commands to give. This is the GUI update manager. The step that fails is "setting new software channels." Of course, this is the problem with GUIs that don't work - often they give you little or useless diagnostic information.
